# ActionController::ParameterMissing in Rails 4 (param is missing or the value is empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Tried to add a second Devise#model namespaced to 'affiliates'

```
namespace :affiliates do
  devise_for :account, controllers: { registrations: 'accounts/registrations' }
end
```

In registrations_controller I have this:

```
class Accounts::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'agent_sign_up'

  def new
    cookies.signed[:signup_affiliate] = JSON.generate({
      level: 'affiliate', 
      sponsoring_affiliate: 'TEMP'
    })

    cookie = JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:signup_affiliate])
    @account_subscription_level = cookie['level']
    @affiliate = cookie['sponsoring_affiliate']
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  private
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:sponsoring_affiliate, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I get the following error when trying to register a new affiliate:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in Accounts::RegistrationsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: account

Extracted source (around line #21):

  private
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:sponsoring_affiliate, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

But my LOG shows all of the params being processed:

```
Started POST "/affiliates/account" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-07 14:04:52 -0400
Processing by Accounts::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q9dbDloMiYzlMqHLJlAz0QamnT3hRiOB8xh9/UhLG+o=", "affiliates_account"=>{"email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "account_subscription_level"=>"affiliate", "sponsoring_affiliate"=>"TEMP"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Completed 500  in 1ms
```

**Why am I getting this error? Can anyone help me debug? Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sign_up_params` method is looking for `params[:account]` but you're passing `params[:affiliates_account]`. Make sure your form is passing the `account` object properly.

Comment: How do I do that exactly? Thanks for your help

Comment: I just changed this: `params.require(:affiliates_account).permit...` and it seems to save properly on the account model. Is this because of my namespace in the route?

Comment: Awesome what the namespaced version of current_user? I'm guessing `current_affiliate_account` but that doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see what end points you need. Also, look through the [Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for other solutions (i.e. `devise_scope`) besides namespacing the routes.